# Find and Grep working properly via prompt but not via Jenkins

Tags: command-line, grep, find, regex, jenkins

I´m trying to filter some files using `find` and `grep` via the command below:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q --exclude=*.{cpp,gradle,java,ttf,txt,xml,md} . {} \; -and -print
```

The funny thing is: via command in the server prompt is working fine but via a Shell build step is kinda not. Kinda because if I remove the `{}` that surround the file types and leave e.g. `--exclude=*.java` it works.

My questions are:

1. What’s going on?
2. Can I do it in another way in the regexp?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "kinda not" working? what shell does Jenkins use? My guess is that it does not support brace expansion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was testing the server `bash` but my Jenkins was configured to use `sh`. Once I fix this configuration aiming the Shell scripts to run over `/bin/bash` worked properly.